# REST Client in Akka with Java

Tags: java, java-8, akka

Is there any seamless mechanism for executing restful requests from Akka (using akka with java only). There is a spray client http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-client/ but it seams there is no api for java nor ssl support.
Also there is Akka-Http package but is still experimental and I could not find a description of the client api.

So far I have one approach to use jersey client (https://jersey.java.net) and hide synchronous calls behind an Akka router with some pool of actors doing this job.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Akka HTTP ships with a client API, and as everything backed by Typesafe, we also provided a Java API for it. [Documentation for the client side API is available online.](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/java/http/client-side/index.html)

There's a number of different APIs to chose from, read the above documentation, but the simplest one is `singleRequest`:

```
// valid for Akka Http 1.0 (experimental), APIs may change slightly still
final ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create();
final ActorMaterializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);

final Future<HttpResponse> responseFuture =
  Http.get(system)
    .singleRequest(HttpRequest.create("http://akka.io"), materializer);
```

Akka HTTP does support TLS/SSL. One thing it differs from [Play's WS](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/3.0.x/ScalaWS) is that it's more low level, and gives you more control over how/when/what. WS is simpler to use and also asynchronous. *Akka HTTP is able to **stream** the response body*, whereas WS and some other HTTP clients are not able to do this. The streaming is achieved using [Akka Streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/java/stream-quickstart.html), by getting the response body stream: `response.entity().getResponseBytes()` which is a `Source<ByteString, ?>`.

Either Play's WS or Akka HTTP's client-side should do everything you need, pick which fits your use-case more. If you need streaming - Akka, if you need very simple things - Play.

---

Follow up, if you're making Http Requests from an Actor and want responses to come back as messages. You can use the pipeTo pattern to pipe the `Future` back to the `Actor` like so:

```
import static akka.pattern.Patterns.pipe;
// ... 

Future<HttpResponse> response = Http.get(system)
  .singleRequest(HttpRequest.create("http://akka.io"), materializer);
pipe(response, context.dispatcher()).to(self);
```

Comment: This example is more like for using externally of an actor system. If I want to make an http request from within an actor, can I receive the response like a message in the actor queue?

Comment: Sure, just use the `pipeTo` pattern to get the `Future` back as a message, I'll update the answer above.

Comment: I've added documentation (a full example) for using the HTTP client in Actors to the documentation, here's the PR: https://github.com/akka/akka/pull/18611 Happy hakking!

Comment: hello Konrad.... i am trying to use your code, but the "singleRequest" method returns me a "CompletionStage<HttpResponse>" and i cannot convert it to a "Future<HttpResponse>"... can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Just stick to using completion stage. T hats the new java api

Comment: This answer is 2 years old and it's already outdated. Welcome to the new world of non-backwards compatible tools. This code doesn't work. Response type is `CompletionStage<HttpResponse>` Eclipse says `The method pipe(Future<T>, ExecutionContext) in the type Patterns is not applicable for the arguments (CompletionStage<HttpResponse>, ExecutionContextExecutor)`